# Nodejs - Timeout with a await function (if does not complete, throw new Error)

Tags: node.js

This is my code:

```
router.post('/route', indexValidator, async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const data = await action.access(req);
    res.send(data);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

I'd like to return an error 'throw new Error()' if the 'await action.access(req);' take more than 60 seconds. How can I do that ?

I tried this:

```
router.post('/route', indexValidator, async (req, res, next) => new Promise(async (resolve, rej) => {
  try {
    let data;
    setTimeout(async () => {
      rej(new Error('No more time'));
    }, 3000);

    resolve(data = await action.access(req));
    res.send(data);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
}));
```

But the code keeps running, and I get this error when the timeout runs:

```
(node:8765) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No more time
```

Answer (score -1):

So in this problem, you have to clear the timeout if you get the data within 60 seconds. So you can do something like this

```
router.post('/route', indexValidator, async (req, res, next) => new Promise(async (resolve, rej) => {
  try {
    let data;
    const timer = setTimeout(async () => {
      rej(new Error('No more time'));
    }, 1000 * 60);
    const data = await action.access(req);
    clearTimeout(timer)
    resolve(data);
    res.send(data);
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
 }));
```

Comment: (node:18211) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No more time

Comment: After how much time you are getting the error, mostly with 3 sec? I have changed the timeout to 60 seconds now.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you create a promise at router handler. Instead of throwing error you should send an error message to client. Try below example. Hope this will help you.

```
var apiRouter = require('express').Router();

apiRouter.post('/', async(req, res, next) => {
console.log('Request Came..');
setTimeout(() => {
    next(new Error('TimedOut'));
}, 2000);
try {
    var data = await test();
    res.send(data);
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error');
}

});

function test() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('response');
    }, 6000);
});
}

module.exports = apiRouter;
```